# How I can edit my response to 1 row + add condition to jq function

Tags: bash, jq, aws-cli

Hey I am using the next command

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes  --filters Name=status,Values=available | jq '.Volumes[] | { State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags}'
```

I get the next response:

```
{
 "State": "available",
"VolumeId": "vol-03449dadd29f2067f",
"Tags": [
{
  "Key": "sre",
  "Value": "test"
}
]}
```

1.I want my response will be in 1 row regarding each volume.
2. I want to check if the volume has the tag "Name" if so I want the value, otherwise the tags are not interest me. How can I manipulate it ?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the -c option.
2. Use a query of the form `select(any(Tags[]; CONDITION))`
   e.g.  select(any(Tags[]; .Key == "Name"))
3. You can abbreviate expressions of the form {foo: .foo} to just {foo}

So, depending on your exact requirements, your invocation of jq could look like:

```
jq -c '.Volumes[] | {State, VolumeId, Tags} | select(any(.Tags[]; .Key == "Name"))'
```

Comment: Can you explain me .
How it returns me  the value of "State" and "VolumeIId"?

Comment: I have 2 volumes

** 1.{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-0782e616a63cebb89","Tags":[{"Key":"user","Value":"Sre"},{"Key":"Name","Value":"Adi"}]} **

2.{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-0df1af4186789efc2","Tags":[{"Key":"team","Value":"sre"}]} 

For the first volume I want output

{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-0782e616a63cebb89","Tags":[{"Name":"Adi"}]}

For the 2nd 
{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-0df1af4186789efc2"}

I mean - I want check if there is a "Name" in tags -> If so print it.
Else don't print tags